# Query with Criteria is not returning accurate or relevant results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a data set of 9 records in a table that is test data.
I have a sample of the data below.
In the table below, the first line is the header.

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| BehrInvoice |  TboInvoice |  TboRloc |     TboDoc    |     TboPax    |
+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
|        4312 |  1449S      |  WIUBLF  |  -0772089627  |  ASARCH/CHAD  |
|        4313 |  1457S      |  TAQXKU  |  XD7366998723 |  CARREON JR/L |
|        4314 |  1457S      |  TAXXKU  |  -7366998723  |  CARREON JR/L |
|        4317 |  1461S      |  TOXSEH  |  XD7366998726 |  ALVA/MICHAEL |
|        4318 |  1460S      |  TOXSEH  |  -7366998726  |  ALVA/MICHAEL |
|        4320 |  1458S      |  ULHHZO  |  -7366998724  |  GREENFIELD/M |
+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

What I would like to do is be able to search each of the columns,
together.

I would expect that if I typed in `alva` I would see 
the `Alva/Michael` records pop up, at least first.

Or if I typed in the `TboInvoice` search box `1458`, and `alva` in the
`TboPax` search box, I would see all three of those records.

I was trying to use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Main
WHERE ((Main.TboInvo) LIKE [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "*")
OR ((Main.TboPax) LIKE [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] & "*")
```

But the result set came back with everything.
I isolated to the TboInvoice, and tried this:

```
WHERE ((Main.TboInvo) = [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "[S]")
```

and it brought back nothing.

I suppose I should focus on just `TboInvoice` here, and get that running properly.

So, in summary, the question is:

How do I query the `TboInvoice` column here and get more accurate results?

===
EDIT 190906

So when I put in:

```
SELECT * FROM Main​ 
WHERE​ Main.TboPax LIKE "alva*"​;
```

it worked perfectly.
when I put in:

```
SELECT *
FROM Main
WHERE (((Main.TboPax) Like [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName]));
```

AND the value on the form of [PaxName]== "alva", i get nothing. Maybe I am referencing the form incorrectly?

Comment: I NEVER use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report.

Comment: Remove the brackets from `"[S]"`. Regardless, you won't get what you want with multiple dynamic parameters if any does not have input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your first query returns everything is because if either of the textboxes `TboInvoice` or `PaxName` are empty, then `[Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "*"` will yield `"*"`, thus matching all records.

With this in mind, you will need to include a test within your selection criteria to account for when the form control is null, perhaps something along the lines of:

```
select * from main
where
(
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] is not null and 
    main.tboinvo like [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "*"
) or
(
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] is not null and 
    main.tbopax like [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] & "*"
)
```

Depending on the desired behaviour, you may want **all** records to be returned if **both** form controls are null, which would require a third condition such as:

```
select * from main
where
(
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] is not null and 
    main.tboinvo like [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "*"
) or
(
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] is not null and 
    main.tbopax like [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] & "*"
) or
( 
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] is null and
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] is null
)
```

This could alternatively be written:

```
select * from main
where
(
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] is null or
    main.tboinvo like [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "*"
) and 
(
    [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] is null or 
    main.tbopax like [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] & "*"
)
```

And noting that `Null & "*"` yields `"*"`, this could become:

```
select * from main
where
    main.tboinvo like [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "*"
    and 
    main.tbopax like [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] & "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you simply want `and`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Main
WHERE (Main.TboInvo LIKE [Forms]![SearchForm]![TboInvoice] & "*") AND
      (Main.TboPa LIKE [Forms]![SearchForm]![PaxName] & "*")
```

If you use `OR` and leave either text box empty, then all rows are included by the condition for that text box.